# document.write() works inline but not using jQuery's .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, document.write

If I have a `document.write` already in my dom as the page loads, it writes only where it's called to write. For example:

```
<div id="d1">
existing text <script>document.write('& doc written text');</script>
</div>
<div>footer</div>
```

Will render as `<div id="d1">existing text & doc written text</div><div>footer</div>`

However, if I were to use jQuery to update the html within div, like

```
$("#d1").html("another approach <script>document.write('wipes out the screen');</script>");
```

I end up simply with `wipes out the screen` b/c it essentially gets rid of everything in the document, vs. writing only where the inline script is. How can I `.html()` with a value containing `document.write()`, but have it behave the same as if it were in the dom to begin with (see first example). Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `document.write()` after DOM is loaded, otherwise it will erase your entire document. Is there a reason you want to use it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page has fully been written, you can not use document.write(). There is nothing you can do to change how it behaves. You need to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Nothing? `document.write = function () { alert("hello world"}); }` :)

Comment: @paislee Yes you can override document.write, but I would like to see you get that text in the same location as it would be when the page is rendered.

Comment: Perfect answer, and that's exactly what we had to do - rework the whole thing after stepping back. `document.write` can be dangerous, we've learned! (and powerful)

Answer (score 4):

The `html()` function **replaces** the contents of an element. [(See the API)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

What you want is [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).